How often should I replace my tires on my mountain bike?
I ride a Canondale mountain bike that I bought 20 years ago now.  It is in mint condition becuase after every muddy ride I clean it up.  There have been periods of time, years, when my bike simply hung in my garage and then I get inspired and have time to ride again. I am curious if there is a recommendation on when the tires should be replaced? Is it like a car where when you see visible wearing?

Welcome to the site - could you please [edit] into your question a closeup photo of the sidewall of your tyre, and the tread, and perhaps an overall photo of your bike from the right-hand side.

At 20 years old, I would suggest replacing if you can afford it, but there is no real recommended replacement time.
Generally, Mountain bike tires will show signs of problems long before they fail catastrophically. Unlike road tires, MTB tires are built strong to handle trail conditions, which makes them resilient to the problems caused from aging. While they will age, it would have to be extreme to lead to catastrophic failure. As they age their performance degrades, so many people will replace tires that other consider have plenty of life. This leaves the replacement decision pretty much up to when the rider feels it is needed.
Two things happen with age - the tread wears down to the point there is not enough for the conditions, the rider is loose traction when a new tire would not. The other thing that happens is the tire rubber is hardening from the day it was manufactured. The hard rubber has less friction, and deforms less, so traction is reduced with age.
I am certain you would get benefit from new tires, but it is not a no-cost exercise, perhaps you would prefer the money be spent elsewhere. If the tire are worn, replacement would be more beneficial. Main thing to consider is would you (not me, or anyone else who does not ride the bike) benefit from better performance?
Inspect the tires and look for damage and wear, pay attention to sidewalls as well as tread. Drop the pressure (even remove from rim) and feel how they are flexing.
If you decide to replace, you now have a new problem - what with. At 20 years old, they will probably be 26"er's, good replacements are getting harder to find on the shelf at the LBS, but they will likely have to order in for you. While you can order online, your LBS will have local knowledge and be able to advise what style tires suit local conditions.   The choice can be overwhelming. Most manufacturers have with great information in their web sites to guide tire selection.

A complement to this answer: when it comes to drying, other components can have the same behaviour as tires: brake pads if the bike doesn’t have disk brakes (critical for safety, dry pads being much less effective), handle bar grips (not critical).
